# Can someone please draw all the recursive calls for this Code. It's Preorder Traversal of a Tree. Due to that two recursion calls am getting confused

Tags: python, recursion, tree

What will be the Recursive calls for this Question ?

```
def preOrder(rootNode):
    if not rootNode:
        return 
    print(rootNode.data)
    preOrder(rootNode.leftChild)
    preOrder(rootNode.rightChild)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Start with the first call and write `...` for the function's effects -

```
preorder(n1)
...
```

Now fill in the `...`. I'm using indentation to show stack-depth -

```
preorder
print(n1)
  preorder(n2)
  ...
  preorder(n3)
  ...
```

Keep filling in the top-most `...` as this is the order that the program is executed -

```
preorder
  print(n1)
  preorder(n2)
    print(n2)
    preorder(n4)
    ...
    preorder(n5)
    ...
  preorder(n3)
  ...
```

Just keep doing this until there are no more `...` -

```
preorder
  print(n1)
  preorder(n2)
    print(n2)
    preorder(n4)
      print(n4)
      preorder(n9)
      ...
      preorder(n10)
      ...
    preorder(n5)
    ...
  preorder(n3)
  ...
```

On node `n9` we see our first early `return` -

```
preorder
  print(n1)
  preorder(n2)
    print(n2)
    preorder(n4)
      print(n4)
      preorder(n9)
        None
      preorder(n10)
      ...
    preorder(n5)
    ...
  preorder(n3)
  ...
```

Node `n10` also ends at this point -

```
preorder
  print(n1)
  preorder(n2)
    print(n2)
    preorder(n4)
      print(n4)
      preorder(n9)
        None
      preorder(n10)
        None
    preorder(n5)
    ...
  preorder(n3)
  ...
```

We resume with node `n5` which also ends here -

```
preorder
  print(n1)
  preorder(n2)
    print(n2)
    preorder(n4)
      print(n4)
      preorder(n9)
        None
      preorder(n10)
        None
    preorder(n5)
      None
  preorder(n3)
  ...
```

And finally we get to `n3` -

```
preorder
  print(n1)
  preorder(n2)
    print(n2)
    preorder(n4)
      print(n4)
      preorder(n9)
        None
      preorder(n10)
        None
    preorder(n5)
      None
  preorder(n3)
    print(n3)
    preorder(n6)
    ...
    preorder(n7)
    ...
```

Fast-forward to the end -

```
preorder
  print(n1)
  preorder(n2)
    print(n2)
    preorder(n4)
      print(n4)
      preorder(n9)
        None
      preorder(n10)
        None
    preorder(n5)
      None
  preorder(n3)
    print(n3)
    preorder(n6)
      None
    preorder(n7)
      None
```